# Jersey : Is it possible to specify multiple values in @DefaultValue() annotation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am playing around with *Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS)* ,
and encountered `@DefaultValue` annotation in Jersey implementation of JAX-RS.

Here is the code snippet

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
public Response getUserWithQueryParams(
    @DefaultValue("defaultId") @QueryParam("from")String from,
    @DefaultValue("defaultName") @QueryParam("to") String to,
    @DefaultValue("mobileNo")@QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy
                                        ){
```

My third argument is of `List<String>`  which can have multiple values

for example I explicitly pass the parameters

```
users/query?from=100&to=200&orderBy=age&orderBy=name
```

Now my third argument have values `[age,name]` ,

but if i don't pass any explicitly parameter then Is there any way to set **multiple default values** . ?

Comment: why not just check if `orderBy` is null then if it is populate the `List` with your default values...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html

Comment: @brso05 , Why i need to check it manually when it gets done itself  , if I don't send any `orderBy` in request it will be replaced by `mobileNo` itself but i want to populate the list with more than 1 default values !!

Comment: @NeerajJain check out my answer I am trying to tell you what you are trying to do is not possible.  You shouldn't use `@DefaultValue` at all you should check if `orderBy == null` then populate if it does.  If you look at the link I posted you will see it says you can't do that...

Comment: @brso05 , ok got it !! your suggestion is nice , waiting for some more alternatives !!

Answer (score 2):

This won't work how you want it to.  If the object is type List it will have a single value inserted in the list.  The object in the list will be the value of your default value for the list.  [Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) Why not try checking if `orderBy == null` if it does then add your default values to `orderBy`?

Comment: i just wanted to know , if that is possible or not ?? I know i can do it manually that is not a big deal , but curious about automatic replacement with multiple values