# Multiple default values for collections with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey and want a set that, when not added as a query param, defaults to a set containing more than one object.

I basically want this:

```
@DefaultValue("test1", "test2")
@QueryParam("test")
private Set<MyEnum> test;
```

to return a set containing the enums "test1" and "test2".
I'm having no problem getting a single default value to work but I would like multiple. The docs are a bit cryptical, is it possible?

Comment: Which documentation are you looking at? The javadoc of the annotation is pretty clear about there being **one** default value.

Comment: The latest doc, it says it will map the default value to a single object. Not whetever it is possible to use multiple default values somehow to map to different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [source from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651066/jersey-is-it-possible-to-specify-multiple-values-in-defaultvalue-annotation) and [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) you can only do this by manually checking if the object is null then set the default value

Comment: How did my search not find that so-answer.. Oh well, I guess it is not possible :(